# Generation Mean Analysis data analysis with R

Tags: analysis

I collected data on crosses that I made (six generations: P1, P2, F1, BC1P1, BC1P2, and F2) for Generation Mean Analysis. By which script and package may I analyse the data to get each generation's mean and genetic parameters?

Answer (score 0):

There is no R package currently for you to do Generation mean analysis.